# Cannot find module in AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm getting this error when I upload and test my AWS Lambda function:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'elasticsearch'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:12:17)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/PublishElasticsearch.js:17:21)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:409:26)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:343:32)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)"
  ]
}
```

and the line of code that `require()`s the module:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch')({
    host: config.ElasticHost
});
```

The function runs successfully the only issue is requiring my module.

I run `npm install` in the function directory and my ZIP that I upload is structured like this:

```
PublishElasticsearch.zip
    PublishElasticsearch.js
    node_modules
        elasticsearch
```

Does anyone know why I would be getting this error?

Comment: Sometimes I've noticed that if there's an error in the module, node will report that the module is missing.  Double check your elasticsearch module that there are no errors on load, and also verify that any dependencies it requires is also part of your zip.

Comment: Can you make sure you have `elasticsearch ` as one of the dependencies in your package.json.

Answer (score 4):

I had all modules listed under **devDependencies**. Moving everything over to **dependencies** solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this anwser here: [aws-lambda Cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678348/aws-lambda-cannot-find-module)

looks like is the same problem you might have

Comment: This is an entirely different issue; the question you linked is unable to find the handler file (PublishElasticsearch.js, in this case), while this question is about finding a dependency. (That may sound like a nitpick, but it boils down to "the solutions to the linked question are entirely irrelevant to this situation.")