# Facing issues when uploaded a zip code in aws lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am new to aws and just started working around with aws lambda by following some youtube tutorials and was able to write aws lambda functions successfully on the web editor itself.

But I tried with the uploading zip file from my local system in which i wrote a node.js code that use modules "fs" and "fill-pdf". But when I tried to run the code it was giving me error.

"error" : module not found "/var/task/index".
I searched through internet and found some links like :
     https://github.com/lob/lambda-pdftk-example
I tried this but it also shows same error.

Here is my code :

```
    var index = require('index');
    var fillPdf = require("fill-pdf");
    var fs = require('fs');
    var formDate = {
    'Employee Name': 'MyName',
    'Company Name': 'ComapnyName'
     };
    var pdfTemplatePath = "my.pdf";


    fillPdf.generatePdf(formDate, pdfTemplatePath, function(err,   
    output) {
    if ( !err ) {

         fs.writeFile('message.pdf', output, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('It\'s saved! in same location.');
    });
     }
   });
```

The thing is that I don't know what could be the reason that this error is coming.Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there anymore error information you can include?

Comment: {
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/index'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:12:17)"
  ]
}

Comment: Solved : My mistake in node modules folder there was no index module. Aso I must write a handler function that will be in the way aws lambda understands.Direct node js code will not run in aws lambda.

Answer (score 29):

Make sure you're not zipping the folder, but its contents. Check that your zip contains `index.js` in its root level

Comment: Oh you're kidding... I wasted 3 hours of my life going through the code and trying to figure out what's wrong :(

Comment: @lyoseg, if you don't zip the folder, how do you upload it to amazon? You can only select a folder ending in .zip?

Comment: @arcom I meant you should zip the folder's contents, not the folder itself. (meaning that when you unzip it you get the files, not the folder)

Comment: Got it @lyosef. If others get confused, you should go inside your "lambda_function" folder. Right click and select all the contents (e.g index.js, node_modules, package.json) and then select compress. This will, on my mac at least, create a file called Archive.zip. That is what you will upload to AWS.

Answer (score 2):

The error may occur due to the following :

```
1. Properly zip the folder wait for it's zipping process completion and 
 then upload.

2. First run the main.js file locally like using node main.js and check 
 are there any errors showing in the terminal window, if it does then 
 fix them and then upload.

3. Also there must be handler file that lambda needs, which is must 
  so if you have the handler.js file then when in aws lambda you 
 create a lambda function and check the configuration setting there 
 then do update the name of the handler file name with yours like by 
 default it is index.js may be you would have lambda.js do change it 
 with lambda name (example lambda.handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `var index = require('index');` as it is not used in your code. I'm not sure why it can't find the module after installing it, but in you current example you don't need it.

Comment: Yes I removed. Actually I also followed this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678348/aws-lambda-cannot-find-module

Comment: Now the error has changed. It is     {
  "errorMessage": "Process exited before completing request"
}

Comment: If there is any more code changes, and a new error then please update your question.

Comment: No sir there is no code change and no new error message.

Answer (score 0):

> This error occurs it means your zip is
>   not in valid form in which aws demands.

**If you double click on zip you will find your folder inside that your code file,but lambda wants that when you double click on zip it shoud show direct code files.**

> To achive this:

```
open terminal  
cd your-lambda-folder 
zip -r index.zip *
```

**then upload index.zip to lambda**