# AWS Lambda Error: "Cannot find module '/var/task/index'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, request, aws-lambda

**Node.js Alexa Task Issue**

I'm currently coding a Node.js Alexa Task via AWS Lambda, and I have been trying to code a function that receives information from the OpenWeather API and parses it into a variable called `weather`. The relevant code is as follows:

```
var request = require('request');
var weather = "";
function isBadWeather(location) {
      var endpoint = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + location + "&APPID=205283d9c9211b776d3580d5de5d6338";
      var body = "";
      request(endpoint, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                  body = JSON.parse(body);
                  weather = body.weather[0].id;
            }
      });
}

function testWeather()
{
      setTimeout(function() {
      if (weather >= 200 && weather < 800)
            weather = true;
      else
            weather = false;
      console.log(weather);
      generateResponse(buildSpeechletResponse(weather, true), {});
      }, 500);
}
```

I ran this snippet countless times in Cloud9 and other IDEs, and it seems to be working flawlessly. However, when I zip it into a package and upload it to AWS Lambda, I get the following error:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/index'",
    "errorType": "Error",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)",
        "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
        "require (internal/module.js:12:17)"
    ]
}
```

I installed module-js, request, and many other Node modules that should make this code run, but nothing seems to fix this issue. Here is my directory, just in case:

```
- planyr.zip
   - index.js
   - node_modules
   - package.json
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Here is the log output for my code:

`START RequestId: 46c71292-debf-11e6-a013-1be2c415a9c1 Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'index': Error
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
END RequestId: 46c71292-debf-11e6-a013-1be2c415a9c1
REPORT RequestId: 46c71292-debf-11e6-a013-1be2c415a9c1 Duration: 55.76 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 16 MB `

Comment: In addition to the answer on zipping using terminal on a Mac, also make sure your codefile is called 'index.js'. Mine had a more descriptive name, generating the error.

Comment: @Art This was my issue.  I zipped up a test.js and it threw an unhandled error.  After changing it to index.js it worked fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Fixed it! My issue was that I tried to zip the file using my Mac's built-in compression function in Finder.

If you're a Mac user, like me, you should run the following script in terminal when you are in the root directory of your project (folder containing your `index.js`, `node_modules`, etc. files).

```
zip -r ../yourfilename.zip *
```

For Windows:

```
Compress-Archive -LiteralPath node_modules, index.js -DestinationPath yourfilename.zip
```

Comment: i was zipping like so: "zip -r folder folder.zip" and of course this failed. thanks for the tip to just zip the files and not the directory

Comment: How about windows?

Comment: also make sure to name the function `index.js`

Comment: Is there any way to do this from outside the directory?

Comment: @andrhamm Yes. The format is `zip -r /path/to/destination.zip /path/to/source/directory/*`. That zips the contents of the directory. If you want to zip the directory itself too, use /path/to/source/directory without the *.

Comment: in windows git bast throwing error "command not found", how to resolve this any idea ?

Comment: If you have an issue with your node modules after uploading the zip you created using the zip command here, check to see that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54426847/2320598) issue didn't happen to you. Looks like `Compress-Archive` can cause the node modules to be uploaded as a flat tree. Also if you have a number of dev dependencies, be sure to delete your node modules folder first and use the `npm install --production` to save space!

Comment: This is exactly what I do before uploading my lambda zip file.

Answer (score 26):

Check that file name and handler name are same:

[image: In this case we expect that all our code will be in <code>bundle.ls</code> file]

That means that `zip` file has `bundle.js` file that exports `handler` function:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {//...}
```

Comment: Good catch and thanks for the help. I created a new lambda but missed to update the handler name facing /var/task dir issue.

Answer (score 25):

**Update to the accepted answer:** When this error occurs, it means your zip file is not in the valid form which AWS requires.

**If you double click on zip you will find your folder inside that your code file,but lambda wants that when you double click on zip it shoud show direct code files.**

To achieve this:

```
open terminal  
cd your-lambda-folder 
zip -r index.zip *
```

Then, upload `index.zip` to AWS Lambda.

Comment: in windows git bast throwing error "command not found", how to resolve this any idea ?

Comment: This is command of Ubuntu , please google it for windows or how to create zip from command prompt

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was because I had the handler file in inner src directory.

I had to change the 'Handler' property within Lambda from:

```
index.handler
```

to

```
src/index.handler
```

Comment: I also ran in to this; [Windows] it was simply that I was right clicking on the `API` part of my repo and using `Send To > Compressed Folder`. This creates a zip with structure `api/etc`, hence the exception!

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a permissions issue with files inside your deployment zip.
Try `chmod 777` your files before packaging them in a zip file.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to fix the issue. I tried compressing the `planyr` folder within another folder to no avail. My handler name and main JavaScript file names match (`index`).

Comment: `chmod 777` is a bad advice... this is opening permissions to public to write, read and execute.  Please always find the route cause of the issue. Always try to understand the security implications of executing whatsoever someone in the internet tell you to do. Security is important and must be in our code by default.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the archive contained a folder "src" with index.js file, so I had to put to the handler: "src/index.handler"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to replace

```
exports.handler = function eventHandler (event, context) {
```

with

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was using `lambci/lambda:nodejs8.10` in windows.

I'd tried all of the solution listed above but none of which could help me deal with my issue(even though the error stack look the same as the question).

Here is my simple solution:

1. using `--entrypoint` flag to run a container to find out if the file is mounted into the container. It turns out I may got the share drive issue with my Docker Desktop.
2. I switched my docker daemon that day before, but everything works fine except this problem.
3. Anyway, remount my drive to Docker Desktop, you can both use the `docker` command or just open the Docker Desktop setting to apply.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by Node running out of memory. I fixed that by adding `--memory-size 1500` to my `aws lambda create-function ...` command.