# cannot find module ./dist/server when deploying to AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I had a simple Serverless website running in AWS lambda using node `serverless deploy`, I then added more stuff to the site and updated to the latest version of serverless, now when I deploy the site and visit the URL I get:

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

When I visit the lambda console I get:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module './dist/server'",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module './dist/server'",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
    "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
    "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)",
    "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"
  ]
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

**More Info**

Based on @Amit Baranes comment below which references [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750026/aws-lambda-error-cannot-find-module-var-task-index) here is a Angular site. I don't quite understand what I need to change the handler name to to match my site structure. I am not bundling the files into a .zip myself, but am running the `serverless deploy` command through node:

Here is the website serverless.yml

```
# generated by @ng-toolkit/serverless
service: serverless-site

plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  memorySize: 192
  timeout: 10
  stage: production
  region: us-east-1

package:
  exclude:
   - src/**
   - node_modules/**
   - firebug-lite/**
   - e2e/**
   - coverage/**
   - '!node_modules/aws-serverless-express/**'
   - '!node_modules/binary-case/**'
   - '!node_modules/type-is/**'
   - '!node_modules/media-typer/**'
   - '!node_modules/mime-types/**'
   - '!node_modules/mime-db/**'

custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - '*/*'

functions:
  api:
    handler: lambda.universal
    events:
      - http: ANY {proxy+}
      - http: ANY /
```

Here is my project file structure (starting inside the src directory) for the website.

[image]
[image]

Here is the website lambda function when it is deployed:

[image]

Since the function didn't have a server.js. I attempted to create is by modifying server.ts and putting it in the folder with no luck:

```
// generated by Paul
//import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
//import 'reflect-metadata';

var express =require('express');
var cors= require('cors');
var compression =require('compression');

var join=require('path').join;

export const app = express();

app.use(compression());
app.use(cors());

const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/serverless-site');

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER), {
    maxAge: '1y'
}));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(join(DIST_FOLDER + '/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Check that file name and handler name are same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750026/aws-lambda-error-cannot-find-module-var-task-index

Comment: @AmitBaranes Any idea what the handler name for an Angular site would be?

Comment: Try lambda.js...

Comment: Tried that, but got the same error unfortunately

Comment: Sorry for the late response, any updaet?

Comment: No, everything Im finding seems to point to an error in the node deployment package. About to try deploying it directly on a server and see if I get the same error

Comment: Hey, @Rilcon42 any luck? I am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that ****server.js**** is not created in the **dist** folder.

I got it working by running `npm run build:server:prod` before `serverless deploy`

The relevant line in my package.json looks as follows:

`"build:server:serverless": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js"`

This is probably not the right way to do it, but it solved the issue of not finding ./dist/server and got me to the next error:

```
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "express is not a function",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: express is not a function",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/dist/server.js:9231:15)",
        "    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/dist/server.js:21:30)",
        "    at /var/task/dist/server.js:85:18",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/dist/server.js:88:10)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
        "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)"
    ]
}
```

I got the express error fixed by setting `esModuleInterop = false` in the tsconfig file, thanks to [AWS Serverless Lambda + Angular - TypeError: express is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877539/aws-serverless-lambda-angular-typeerror-express-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score -1):

I do see you are using the `ng-toolkit` package in order to provide universal + serverless for your Angular App.

Based on that, I do think you are receiving such error due to either bad config on latest version of the package, which includes some bugs on the server file along with mismatch with the `Angular/Universal` package.

I do recommend checking out my sample repo in the meantime [Example Angular ng-toolkit](https://github.com/KingDarBoja/example-angular-ng-toolkit), which already fixes that.

Just to point out: this is caused by `webpack.config` option `externals` which was introduced on latest `express-engine` schematic of the Angular Universal packages. Commenting that line, will fix your issue.

The reason is still unknown for me at the moment but hopefully I will bring my findings on this topic.

Cheers!