# AWS Serverless Lambda + Angular - TypeError: express is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

The application works fine in localhost:4200. But when I move to AWS via serverless Lambda, I get this error in cloudwatch logs. And I guess because of that I am getting `500 {"message": "Internal server error"}` when I access the url

I have no knowledge about AWS. Just trying to run a hello world application in AWS. Followed below youtube and blogs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3t8cjykf00

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-6LtzJezsk

https://www.twilio.com/blog/angular-universal-javascript-node-js-aws-lambda

```
2020-03-26T22:48:18.030Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "express is not a function",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: express is not a function",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/dist/server.js:95287:15)",
        "    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/dist/server.js:21:30)",
        "    at module.exports.extendStatics (/var/task/dist/server.js:85:18)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/dist/server.js:88:10)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
        "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)"
    ]
}
```

serverless.yml

```
# generated by @ng-toolkit/serverless
service: app2

plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary
  - serverless-api-compression

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  memorySize: 192
  timeout: 10
  stage: production
  region: eu-central-1

package:
  exclude:
   - src/**
   - node_modules/**
   - firebug-lite/**
   - e2e/**
   - coverage/**
   - '!node_modules/aws-serverless-express/**'
   - '!node_modules/binary-case/**'
   - '!node_modules/type-is/**'
   - '!node_modules/media-typer/**'
   - '!node_modules/mime-types/**'
   - '!node_modules/mime-db/**'

custom:
  contentCompression: 1024
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - '*/*'

functions:
  api:
    handler: lambda.universal
    events:
      - http: ANY {proxy+}
      - http: ANY /
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "@babel/compat-data": "^7.8.0",
    "@ng-toolkit/serverless": "^8.1.0",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^7.1.2",
    "@nguniversal/common": "0.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "0.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "0.0.0",
    "aws-serverless-express": "^3.3.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "domino": "^2.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "serverless-api-compression": "^1.0.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "opencollective": "^1.0.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "serverless": "^1.60.0",
    "serverless-apigw-binary": "^0.4.4",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.0"
  }
```

Comment: Any luck solving this?  I'm getting the same error

Comment: @Lereveme: Not yet. Even I spent a couple of hours last nigh, no luck yet... :(

Answer (score 2):

So I was having a really hard time getting this to work.  I didn't have a specific thing to solve this problem but after some searching stumbled across this github repo.  I downloaded it and the serverless lambda deploy worked correctly.  The example uses angular 8 but hopefully it is the same for 9.

[Angular Serverless Starter Repo](https://github.com/sahilpurav/ngx-serverless-starter)

Comment: You are correct, I didn't get it working, but as you mentioned, with that github repo, I deployed my application in AWS (about 2-3 days back). But I am still trying to understand I am doing wrong when I write the code myself.

Comment: @SK. - I upgraded to 9 and changed a bunch of setting from the starter template to match my project and everything still works.  I was on Angular 7 before and plan to just move the component and artifacts into this new project.  Probably easier.  Good luck

Comment: I did upgrade to 9, but still didn't work. Would you mind providing what all setting changes you did...

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was setting `esModuleInterop = false` in the tsconfig file.

[Found the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61436646/aws-lambda-ng-toolkit-failing-for-typeerror-express-is-not-a-function-in-angul) but didn't have an explanation to it. However, looking at [the official docs for Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), `esModuleInterop` does the following:

> Emit `__importStar` and `__importDefault` helpers for runtime babel ecosystem compatibility and enable `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for typesystem compatibility.

`--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` is defined as:

> Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking.

Maybe enabling `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` along with `esModuleInterop` would be the most efficient and reliable way to go about it. But so far, setting `esModuleInterop` to false worked like a charm.

[Originally found on GitHub.](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1162#issuecomment-490005467)