# AWS Lambda @ng-toolkit failing for TypeError: express is not a function in angular 9 app

Tags: angular, aws-lambda, server-side-rendering

I started deploying my demo Angular 9 application on AWS lambda and provide SSR. In order to achieve this, I used [@ng-toolkit/universal](https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/tree/master/schematics/universal) and [@ng-toolkit/serverless](https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/tree/master/schematics/serverless). Deployment happened successfully but demo application is not opening. Upon investigating AWS lambda logs, I found the following exception.
[image]

Here is the package.json, where I have added express js in dependencies.

```
{
"name": "my-appg",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e",
  "build:browser:prod": "ng build --prod",
  "build:browser:serverless": "ng build --prod --base-href /production/",
  "build:serverless": "npm run build:browser:serverless && npm run build:server:serverless",
  "build:prod": "npm run build:browser:prod && npm run build:server:prod",
  "server": "node local.js",
  "build:prod:deploy": "npm run build:prod && npm run deploy",
  "build:serverless:deploy": "npm run build:serverless && npm run deploy",
  "deploy": "serverless deploy --aws-profile leaks",
  "build:server:prod": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
  "build:server:serverless": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^9.1.3",
  "@angular/animations": "~9.0.5",
  "@angular/common": "~9.0.5",
  "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.5",
  "@angular/core": "~9.0.5",
  "@angular/forms": "~9.0.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.5",
  "@angular/router": "~9.0.5",
  "@ng-toolkit/serverless": "^8.1.0",
  "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^1.1.21",
  "@schematics/angular": "^9.1.3",
  "aws-serverless-express": "^3.3.6",
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
  "serverless-api-compression": "^1.0.0",
  "tslib": "^1.10.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.5",
  "@angular/cli": "~9.0.5",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.5",
  "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.5",
  "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
  "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
  "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "~4.3.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
  "protractor": "~5.4.3",
  "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
  "tslint": "~5.18.0",
  "typescript": "~3.7.5",
  "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
  "opencollective": "^1.0.3",
  "serverless": "^1.60.0",
  "serverless-apigw-binary": "^0.4.4"
}}
```

and here is server.ts which also seems okay.

```
// generated by @ng-toolkit/serverless
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import * as express from 'express';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import * as compression from 'compression';

import {join} from 'path';

export const app = express();

app.use(compression());
app.use(cors());

const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/myPleaks-ng9');

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER), {
    maxAge: '1y'
}));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(join(DIST_FOLDER + '/index.html'));
});
```

Please help me to find out the issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on [github post](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1162#issuecomment-490005467) where "esModuleInterop": true from tsconfig file was required to remove.