# .NET Binaries Missing AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, .net-6.0

I have uploaded a .NET6 project as a zip to AWS Lambda, via Visual Studio --> Publish to AWS Lambda however when I test the lambda, I receive this error:

```
Error: .NET binaries for Lambda function are not correctly installed in the /var/task directory of the image when the image was built. The /var/task directory is missing.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for why this may be happening? Isn't AWS Lambda responsible for including the binaries when you publish as a zip?

Thanks

Comment: https://greghalter.com/aws-lambda-issue-missing-the-required-deps-json-file/

Comment: Unfortunately not, and they don't really go into detail about what the actual conflict between their namespace and project name was. My namespace and project name are completely different however so I don't think this is an issue.

Comment: Did you declare your classes public? Visual Studio nowadays tends to mark things internal?

Comment: Yes, but still having the same issue.

Comment: Same error here, did you found any solution?

Comment: Any solution found for this? I'm facing same issue but I could see the deps.json in build package.
Below is the error I received from lambda..
"Error: .NET binaries for Lambda function are not correctly installed in the /var/task directory of the image when the image was built. The /var/task directory is missing the required .deps.json file."

Comment: Found the issue was with the handler name defined in new lambda created manually in AWS. This post helped me find the issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750026/aws-lambda-error-cannot-find-module-var-task-index

Comment: This may help, doc doesn't explicitly mentioned VScode publishing, You can upload a .zip file as your deployment package using the Lambda console, AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI), or to an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I use **Upload from - .zip** features of Lambda.

[image]

**I uploaded the project in a zip file and binary files were inside the folder. like**

[image]

**That's created an issue. When you upload .zip files, make sure binary files are in the main root.
Not inside any folder.**

Answer (score 1):

do you somehow have the project marked as self-contained on the msbuild parameters? maybe in aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json or  custom runtime set in  serverless.tempate?  It seems it is looking for the dotnet runtime assemblies in your application path

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32875405)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while publishing a lambda via the AWS UI. The problem is that none of the dependencies were being included with the zipped project.

The solution I found was using the .NET command: `dotnet lambda package`.
Running the command in your **project directory** will place the packaged zip in `<project-directory>\bin\Release\net<version>\`. The newly created zip can then be [uploaded to AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html) as a lambda.

If you still plan on using Visual Studio's 'Publish to AWS Lambda' feature as in the original situation, I recommend running the package command as described above before publishing.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another rare but possible reason is an overwritten PATH env var value

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following property to the `csproj` project file, rebuilding and redeploying to Lambda did the trick for me.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Reference: https://mgkeen.com/blog/fixing-runtimeconfigjson-lambda-error

Answer (score 0):

If you come across this issue when using SAM, make sure you execute `sam build` first and then run `sam deploy`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem when using VSCode to create an AWS Lambda. It turns out the ZIP file was missing the needed dependencies. The full error message I was seeing was:

```
Error: .NET binaries for Lambda function are not correctly installed in the /var/task directory of the image when the image was built. The /var/task directory is missing the required .deps.json file.
```

The ZIP file must contain not only your own assembly but any dependent assembles as well. After building your project, open a command prompt and navigate to the location of the project file (e.g., `MyApplication.csproj`). Then, run this command:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish
```

Navigate to the resulting `publish` folder and zip everything (including the `.deps.json` and `.runtimeconfig.json` files) into a ZIP file. (There's no need to include the `.pdb` file.) The name of the ZIP file can be anything -- it does not have to match the name of your assembly or .NET project. Submit the ZIP file to AWS Lambda and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking the lambda configuration in the AWS console.

First, check whether there are any clues in the Code ribbons. If you published through VS, there should be some info like `The deployment package of your Lambda function is too large to enable inline code editing` and `Package size XX.Y MB`. If there is nothing (which I think will be the case), check your publish setup. The lambda runtime container expects code to be present at `/var/task`. If you upload code as zip, it should end up in this directory during lambda container initialization.

This error message might also indicate that a wrong runtime is used (eg. missing the dotnet runtime inside the Amazon Linux container). The structure of the dotnet runtime image can be examined through a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/LambdaRuntimeDockerfiles/Images/net6/amd64/Dockerfile) that the image originates from.

Hope this helps a little .