# AWS Lambda Runtime Error: .NET binaries for Lambda function are not correctly installed in the /var/task directory

Tags: aws-lambda

I am trying to run an AWS Lambda function that I have uploaded via Visual Studio 2022 on a
Windows 10 PC. The function was successfully uploaded as a zip file. There were no errors during the upload. My Lambda function targets the .Net 6 framework using the x86_64 architecture.

When I attempt to run the Lambda function, a failure message is returned immediately. It
reads.

Error: .NET binaries for Lambda function are not correctly installed in the /var/task directory of the image when the image was built. The /var/task directory is missing the required .deps.json file.
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 19.54 ms Phase: init Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
Error: .NET binaries for Lambda function are not correctly installed in the /var/task directory of the image when the image was built. The /var/task directory is missing the required .deps.json file.
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 11.66 ms Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
START RequestId: 2dd64b40-d091-498e-81f5-05154f51a4ef Version: $LATEST
RequestId: 2dd64b40-d091-498e-81f5-05154f51a4ef Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 105
Runtime.ExitError
END RequestId: 2dd64b40-d091-498e-81f5-05154f51a4ef
REPORT RequestId: 2dd64b40-d091-498e-81f5-05154f51a4ef  Duration: 12.53 ms  Billed Duration: 13 ms  Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 3 MB

I inspected the zip file used by the upload. Every dll in that zip file which was created from a visual studio project has a matching deps.json file. Dlls that have been loaded from other
dependencies (e.g. Amazon.Lambda.Core) do not have a json file.

I have tried the suggestions from an earlier post on the same error. A link to that post is included below. None of the suggestions in this post resolve my issue.
[.NET Binaries Missing AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049998/net-binaries-missing-aws-lambda)

There is a blog post that suggests this error may be caused by a namespace conflict; however, no such conflicts exist in my case.
https://greghalter.com/aws-lambda-issue-missing-the-required-deps-json-file/

Any assistance on the error I am experiencing will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When you look at the zip and see it has some deps.json files is there any deps.json that start with the assembly name you used at the start of your function handler value for the Lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause for my error.

In the AWS console, there is a "Handler" setting under "Runtime settings" under the "Code" tab for AWS lambda functions. My value for this setting was incorrect. It needs to be [assembly]::[namespace].[class name containing function handler]::[name of function handler]

Comment: Example: 

HelloWorld::HelloWorld.Function::FunctionHandler