# aws lambda: test event configuration: Error in JSON event

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, callback, aws-lambda

I have deployed a `node js` app to `AWS lambda`. I have the following code in my test event :

```
function getRoutes(callback){
    request('http://localhost/php-rest/api.php/routes?filter=route_short_name', function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            message = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body));
            return callback(message, false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, error);;
        }
    });
}

app.get('/getRoutes', function(req, res) {

    getRoutes(function(err, data){
        if(err) return res.send(err);
        res.send(data);
    });

});
```

I got the following error when I tried to save that:

> There is an error in your JSON event. Please correct it before saving.

Comment: Test events in lambda support only the json format. It defines the event that is passed as an argument to a lambda handler.

Comment: @JaeyeonBaek I am new to this thing. What am I supposed to put in the test event?

Comment: It only use to pass the arguments into lambda function as @JaeyeonBaek said. So that it is better if you can post the lambda handler code here.

Comment: @SameeraPiyasundara I thought that you have to post the handler code in the test event. The code I poster here is the handler code.

Comment: so here you don't have to pass any parameters. therefore just keep the default json which is inside the test and save it by giving a name and run the test after that. So you will get a success or error message after completion. There you can see the error message if you have any errors.

Comment: @SameeraPiyasundara where do I put the handler code then?

Comment: So lambda function is the handler code right? You have deployed it and that's because you get the test functionality for that lambda function. Isn't it?

Did you go through the Create Function wizard?

Comment: How about seeing the manual first? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This is the configuration of lambda function you have created. So click on the lambda function first. After that you will get a window called function code. There you have to write you handler. After that you can test like you did before.
[image][image]

Comment: Oh, so I just upload the lambda function as a zip file?

Comment: So what is the output you got?

Comment: It can't find express module. Did I have to upload node_modules with the rest of my code?

Comment: yes. better check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678348/aws-lambda-cannot-find-module)

Comment: Is the lambda function the only thing that I put in the zip file?

Comment: I uploaded my entire project. Now I am getting this: Process exited before completing request

Comment: I have uploaded my entire project. Now I am getting this error: errorMessage": "Handler 'handle' missing on module 'exports

Comment: I have opened a new question if you still want to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755410/aws-lambda-handler-handle-missing-on-module-exports

Comment: really sorry for the late reply. i will look into the question you have posted.