# AWS lambda: "Handler 'handle' missing on module 'exports'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have uploaded a `node js` express project to `AWS lambda`. The following is my handler code saved as `exports.js`:

```
const
  express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  request = require('request'),
  app = express().use(bodyParser.json()); // creates express http server

exports.handler = function(callback){
    request('http://localhost/php-rest/api.php/routes?filter=route_short_name', function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            message = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body));
            return callback(message, false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, error);;
        }
    });
}

app.get('/exports.handler', function(req, res) {

    exports.handler(function(err, data){
        if(err) return res.send(err);
        res.send(data);
    });

});
```

The handler code is separate from my `app.js` file. I got the following error when I tested it on aws lambda:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'handler' missing on module 'exports'"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]
So this is your lambda function which should be there as a handler. In your code app.get() has to be handled by AWS API Gateway. because it is the method of invocation of lambda functions. You can't have the nodejs server inside the lambda function.

So the .zip file should be named as index.js since when we upload the .zip file it extracts the contents and find the handler name which we have provided. 
These are the .zip file contents that should be uploaded.

- index.js.zip

  - node_modules
  - index.js
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json

Comment: So, the rest of my code should also be inside index.js alongside the handler?

Comment: Yes but you can’t create a server inside lambda function. That will be handled by API Gateway.

Comment: Do I remove 'app = express().use(bodyParser.json());' then? Or is it the app.listen in my other js file?

Comment: Its app.listen() that creates the server

Comment: Do I also need to name my handler index.handler?

Comment: The execution result has succeeded but the URL from API Gateway is still giving an internal server error.

Comment: Yes your url is localhost see the error message you get. You can not send request to localhost from any remote place. Therefore host your php application first.

Comment: php? I am using node js. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Nope i mean that the url you are going to access inside your lambda function is a localhost one.

Comment: Oh, need a  web domain? I thought you didn't need that in lambda.

Comment: http://localhost/php-rest/api.php/routes?filter=route_short_name this url is what I referred to

Comment: So I change it with my domain name?

Comment: Is the request part even necessary?

Comment: Created new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793418/aws-lambda-handler-function-breakdown?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: it's not clear what is your idea of using a lambda function?

Comment: For deploying a we app to aws lambda?

Comment: You can not directly deploy a web app as a lambda function. because lambda function is a light weight function which replaces a single API call. Therefore it is better if you could read this article and understand how to build and deploy a web application in to AWS. [link](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/build-a-web-app/)

Answer (score 3):

This normally appears if you don't have an index and start function. You can define it as index in the export hander:

```
exports.handler = function index(event, context, callback) {
    // Your start code here
}
```

Comment: What are the event and context parameters? How do I call this function later on?

Comment: in event parameter we have all the arguments passed in to the handler method. such as query parameters, post, get params, etc. from context parameter it uses to manipulate the context of the handler method.

Comment: @SameeraPiyasundara How will this change the second half of my code?