# Snowflake NodeJs Error: Cannot find module './data/packed/latest.json'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The following code runs well in local NodeJS process in windows. However, it fails in AWS lambda.

I don't quite understand why it can't load module: **Cannot find module './data/packed/latest.json'**

The lambda event input is:

```
{
    "Service": "snowflake",
    "Profile": "testetl",
    "Interval": 10,
    "Content": "select * from mytable limit 20",
    "Data": null
}
```

The credential is provided in Environment Variable:
testetl: {account:'[my-account]',accessUrl:'https://[my-account].[my-region].snowflakecomputing.com',username:'[my-username]',password:'[my-password]',warehouse:'[my-data-warehouse]',database:'[my-db]',jsTreatIntegerAsBigInt:true}

```js
function connectSnowflake(connection) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.connect((err, conn) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else
                resolve(conn);
        });
    });
}
function executeSnowflake(connection, sqlText) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.execute({
            sqlText: sqlText,
            streamResult: true,
            complete: (err, stmt, rows) => {
                if (err)
                    reject(err);
                else
                    resolve(stmt);
            }
        });
    });
}
function readSnowflakeRows(statement, start, end) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let rows = [];
        statement
            .streamRows({ start: start, end: end })
            .on('error', (err) => {
            throw err;
        })
            .on('data', (row) => {
            for (let key in row) {
                rows.push(row[key]);
                break;
            }
        })
            .on('end', () => resolve(rows));
    });
}
const snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const connection = snowflake.createConnection(eval(`(${process.env[event.Profile]})`));
    let connectionInstance = await connectSnowflake(connection);
    let id = connectionInstance.getId();
    let statement = await executeSnowflake(connection, event.Content);
    let rowsCount = statement.getNumRows();
    let maxRows = Math.min(1000, rowsCount);
    event.Values = await readSnowflakeRows(statement, 0, maxRows);
    return event;
};
```

The error details:

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module './data/packed/latest.json'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/connection/result/sf_timestamp.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/connection/result/column.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/connection/result/result.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/connection/statement.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/connection/connection.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/core.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/snowflake.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/index.js\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module './data/packed/latest.json'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.js",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/connection/result/sf_timestamp.js",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/connection/result/column.js",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/connection/result/result.js",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/connection/statement.js",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/connection/connection.js",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/core.js",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/lib/snowflake.js",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/snowflake-sdk/index.js",
        "- /var/task/index.js",
        "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
        "- /var/runtime/index.js",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)",
        "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)",
        "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11"
    ]
}
```

The package.json file is:

```
{
    "name": "snowflakeclient",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "snowflake-sdk": "^1.5.0"
    },
}
```

Comment: the moment-timezone package  is trying to load it's files `moment.tz.load(require('./data/packed/latest.json'));` so not sure how you inspect files you have loaded to aws-lambda but it would seem to not include that file.

Comment: Thanks! I packed the whole package including node_modules and uploaded the zip to aws lambda. I believe the files should be there, as the package is exactly the same as my local. Not sure if it because of operation system, since aws lambda should be running some version of linux.

Comment: It might be worth double-checking how you are zipping this up and including it to Lamba.  Noticed a few posts with folks having trouble:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678348/aws-lambda-cannot-find-module
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=181471